# Why every request go to index.php

Tags: php

For example I have a project with the structure below

```
project
|_src
|_public
  |_index.php
```

And I run in public folder.

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

When I access

```
http://localhost:8000/random/request/uri
```

Here is the termial when I access the url above;

[image: terminal stdout]

It seems like every url will always go back to index.php file. I wonder why and how. Can anyone explain to me?
I tried to search but I don't know the keyword so....

Comment: Because that's how it's documented to be: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: @HonkderHase — No, this is *not* URL rewriting. (The behaviour *can* be achieved using URL rewriting, but that isn't how it is done here).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález — Ah. I expected there would be something in there but couldn't find it at a quick skim. You prompted me to look harder:  "If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned."

Comment: Can you show the requests on the command line that show up when you try to go to that page?

Comment: I don't see what use the details of the request logging are. The description of the URLs in the question is pretty clear and matches the behaviour described in the documentation (and quoted above).

Comment: @Quentin I was curious if there was a redirect or something else going on. But the output doesn't show anything like that.

Comment: @aynber — Well no. The documentation says the index.php is returned, not that there is a redirect.

Comment: @Quentin Ah. I thought that was just for the current directory, but any subs would look for an index in that subdirectory or return a 404. I was wrong.

Comment: @Quentin was right. The docs is clear. It matches with the behaviour described in my question. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It behaves that way because that is how the PHP built-in development server was designed to work.

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the document root has been reached. **If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned** and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Álvaro González. The answer was documented in https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

"If an index.php or index.html is found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned."